# Add list to list issue in python

Tags: python

```
class Solution(object):
"""
@param candidates: Given the candidate numbers
@param target: Given the target number
@return: All the combinations that sum to target
"""
def combinationSum2(self, candidates, target):
    # write your code here
    candidates.sort()
    self.ans, tmp, use = [], [], [0] * len(candidates)
    self.dfs(candidates, target, 0, 0, tmp, use)
    return self.ans
def dfs(self, can, target, p,
        now, tmp, use):
    if now == target:
        print(tmp)
        self.ans.append(tmp[:])
        return
    for i in range(p, len(can)):
        if now + can[i] <= target and (i == 0 or can[i] != can[i-1] or use[i-1] == 1):
            tmp.append(can[i])
            use[i] = 1
            self.dfs(can, target, i+1, now + can[i], tmp, use)
            tmp.pop()
            use[i] = 0

s = Solution()
can = [10, 1, 2, 7, 6, 1, 5]
tar = 8
print(s.combinationSum2(can,tar))
```

If I replace self.ans.append(tmp[:]) with self.ans.append(tmp), the result will be shown as [[],[],[],[]] but not the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you do `self.ans.append(tmp[:])`, you are appending copy of `tmp` in `self.ans`. Hence, whenever tmp get's added into `self.ans` a new list `tmp` will get added. Hence, even if `tmp` is changed later it won't affect the actual list added to `self.ans`.

Now, when you do `self.ans.append(tmp)`, you are just adding same list `tmp`into `self.ans` instead of it's copy. So later all the operations done on `tmp` also get reflected in `self.ans` since you'd not added the copy of `tmp` but just a reference.
In `dfs` you are doing `tmp.pop()` at 2nd last line, which empties the list `tmp` successively. That's why `self.ans` has all it's `tmp` lists empty.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!